# Jquery retrieving data from multiple data attributes with with array/JSON values

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-selectors, selector, custom-data-attribute

I'm having several elements on my page with the same data attribute, although different values. The elements are formatted like so:

```
<input type="radio" data-toggle='["one","two","three"]'/>
```

Now, I want to get the data from all those elements, and I thought I could just do:

```
var data = $('[data-toggle]').data("toggle");
```

But this only outputs the data from the first element, all other elements with that data-attribute is ignored.

I'm guessing this has to do with it beeing arrays/JSON formatted, but I'm not clear about why this is the case, and how I should go about retrieving all my values.

How can I get all data from all those data attributes?

Here is a fiddle illustrating my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/6u67o9oo/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd have to iterate over each element:

```
$('[data-toggle]').each(function() {
    var data = $(this).data("toggle");

    //Do stuff
});
```

Or you could use `.map` to get a 2D array of all the `data-toggle` attributes:

```
var newArray = $('[data-toggle]').map(function() {
    return $(this).data("toggle");
}).get();
```